# Fixing the stackpointer in IDA when exception handlers are used

Tags: ida

The code that I'm looking at uses exception handlers and it seems that the stack pointer is misscalculated in the case of the exception handler. I posted this function as an exmple in full, so that the problem can be seen.

What I'm interested in is, how I can get rid of the sp-analysis failing.

```
000                 push    ebp
004                 mov     ebp, esp
004                 push    0
008                 push    ebx
00C                 push    esi
010                 mov     ebx, eax
010                 xor     eax, eax
010                 push    ebp
014                 push    offset j_ExceptionHandler1_2
018                 push    dword ptr fs:[eax]
01C                 mov     fs:[eax], esp
01C                 push    1               ; uIDEvent
020                 mov     eax, [ebx+28h]
020                 push    eax             ; hWnd
024                 call    j_KillTimer
01C                 mov     esi, [ebx+24h]
01C                 test    esi, esi
01C                 jz      short loc_4467F1
01C                 cmp     byte ptr [ebx+34h], 0
01C                 jz      short loc_4467F1
01C                 cmp     word ptr [ebx+2Eh], 0
01C                 jz      short loc_4467F1
01C                 push    0               ; lpTimerFunc
020                 push    esi             ; uElapse
024                 push    1               ; nIDEvent
028                 mov     eax, [ebx+28h]
028                 push    eax             ; hWnd
02C                 call    j_SetTimer
01C                 test    eax, eax
01C                 jnz     short loc_4467F1
01C                 lea     edx, [ebp+Str]
01C                 mov     eax, ds:off_5C6E3C
01C                 call    LoadString      ; EAX = StringResource
                                            ; EDX = Target
                                            ;
01C                 mov     ecx, [ebp+Str]
01C                 mov     dl, 1
01C                 mov     eax, off_40CA00
01C                 call    sub_409F34
01C                 call    GlobalExceptionE

    loc_4467F1:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_446788+27j
                                            ; sub_446788+2Dj
                                            ; sub_446788+34j
                                            ; sub_446788+46j
00C                 xor     eax, eax
00C                 pop     edx
008                 pop     ecx
004                 pop     ecx
000                 mov     fs:[eax], edx
000                 push    offset loc_44680E

    loc_4467FE:                             ; CODE XREF: CODE:0044680Cj
004                 lea     eax, [ebp+Str]  ; RDStr
004                 call    ReleaseDelphiString ; EAX = Pointer to a stringpointer
                                            ;
                                            ; Refcount is decreased and the pointer is set to NULL.
004                 retn
    sub_446788      endp ; sp-analysis failed

    ; [00000005 BYTES: COLLAPSED FUNCTION j_ExceptionHandler1_2. PRESS KEYPAD "+" TO EXPAND]
    ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    jmp     short loc_4467FE
    ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ; START OF FUNCTION CHUNK FOR sub_446788

    loc_44680E:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_446788+7Ej
                                            ; DATA XREF: sub_446788+71o
004                 pop     esi
000                 pop     ebx
-04                 pop     ecx
-08                 pop     ebp
-0C                 retn
```

**Update**

The the `GlobalExceptionE` function is this

```
000                 pop     edx
-04                 push    esp
000                 push    ebp
004                 push    edi
008                 push    esi
00C                 push    ebx
010                 push    eax
014                 push    edx
018                 push    esp             ; lpArguments
01C                 push    7               ; nNumberOfArguments
020                 push    1               ; dwExceptionFlags
024                 push    0EEDFADEh       ; dwExceptionCode
028                 push    edx
02C                 jmp     j_RaiseException
```

Comment: First, change the stack pointer at `loc_4467F1` to `01C` and see where that gets you. Right click that line, choose "Change Stack Pointer", enter `0`. Then update your post with the new code if it's still unsatisfactory.

Comment: @DCoder, When I change the value to `0x0C` then of course the Hex Rays plugin no longer complains as the value is 0 on the final return. I took out all the irrelvant parts of the code, just to see only push/and pops and I really don't see why IDA has this stack analysis error in the first place.

Comment: There are ways to change the stack pointer other than `push`/`pop`, including a `call` into a callee-cleanup function. In my experience, this stack pointer problem happens when IDA misidentifies the signature of a function being called and assigns an incorrect delta to the line following that `call` (in your case, I suspect the initial analysis of `GlobalExceptionE` was incorrect). In one previous project I was hitting this problem so often that I wrote [an IDC script](https://github.com/DCoderLT/Misc_Tools/blob/master/idc/stackscan/stackscan.idc) to detect it.

Comment: @DCoder, when I compressed the function into stack relvant instructions, I also had the impression that the `GlobalExceptionE` function should be the cause of it. But somehow I don't see how this should work. I updated the question to show this, and from there it should be obvious why IDA thinks so.

Comment: It's hard to speculate further without a full view of the executable - if you post the executable, it could provide more information. However, you should realize that without having the source to IDA it can't be definitively said what sequence of events causes this problem, we can only theorize.